# Python How to send an attachment with mailgun

Tags: python, django

Good day

I need help please.

I can't send a message with attachment.

This is the relevant resource:

```
def send_email_with_mailgun(sender, recipients, subject, body, mail_gun_url, mailgun_api_key):

   recipients = recipients if type(recipients) is list else [recipients]

   try:
       return requests.post(
         mail_gun_url,
         auth=("api", mailgun_api_key),
         data={"from": sender,
              "to": recipients,
              "subject": subject,
              "text": body},
         files=[("attachment", (open("xxxxxxx.pdf", "rb")))],)

   except: 
       pass
```

If I remove the parameter it does send, otherwise it will not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The docs](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html#examples) suggest that you should have a filename, so something like this?

`requests.post(
         mail_gun_url,
         auth=("api", mailgun_api_key),
         data={"from": sender,
              "to": recipients,
              "subject": subject,
              "text": body},
         files=[("attachment", ("xxxxxxx.pdf", open("xxxxxxx.pdf", "rb").read()))],)`

Comment: Fixed with this and with the another answer.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do if you want to find out what is going wrong is to remove `try...except...pass` (or change `pass` to `raise`). That is suppressing the exception and the exception is the only thing that is going to tell you what is wrong. It could be something entirely unrelated to the attachment. For example, `open()` might be failing because it can't find the file or because you already have it open in another application.

When you have an exception to report then add it to your question.

Comment: A very useful advice.

Thank you so much!